Keep getting error running this script for stock screening and analysis
The script is meant to extract list of stocks symbols and its corresponding data for analysis but i keep getting error when i get to the map section of the code. The script is given below:
 { 
    library(quantmod); library(xts)
    library(rvest); library(tidyverse);
    library(stringr); library(forcats); library(lubridate) 

        sp_500 <- read_html("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies") %>%
        html_node("table.wikitable") %>%
        html_table() %>%
        select(`Symbol`, Security, `GICS Sector`, `GICS Sub-Industry`) %>%
        as_tibble()
        # Format names
        names(sp_500) <- sp_500 %>%
         names() %>%
          str_to_lower() %>%
           make.names()
          colnames(sp_500) <- c("ticker.symbol","security","gics.sector","gics.sub.industry")
        
         get_stock_prices <- function(ticker, return_format = "tibble", ...) {
         # Get stock prices
         stock_prices_xts <- getSymbols(Symbols = ticker, auto.assign = FALSE, ...)
         # Rename
         names(stock_prices_xts) <- c("Open", "High", "Low", "Close", "Volume", "Adjusted")
         # Return in xts format if tibble is not specified
         if (return_format == "tibble") {
         stock_prices <- stock_prices_xts %>%
           as_tibble() %>%
             rownames_to_column(var = "Date") %>%
               mutate(Date = ymd(Date))
               } else {
             stock_prices <- stock_prices_xts
               }
           stock_prices
          }
        
         get_log_returns <- function(x, return_format = "tibble", period = 'daily', ...) {
         # Convert tibble to xts
         if (!is.xts(x)) {
            x <- xts(x[,-1], order.by = x$Date)
              }
         # Get log returns
         log_returns_xts <- periodReturn(x = x$Adjusted, type = 'log', period = period, ...)
         # Rename
         names(log_returns_xts) <- "Log.Returns"
         # Return in xts format if tibble is not specified
           if (return_format == "tibble") {
              log_returns <- log_returns_xts %>%
                 as_tibble() %>%
                   rownames_to_column(var = "Date") %>%
                      mutate(Date = ymd(Date))
               } else {
               log_returns <- log_returns_xts
              }
            log_returns
           }

          # Mapping the Functions --------------------------------------------------------
         from <- "2007-01-01"
         to   <- today()
         sp_500 <- sp_500 %>%
          mutate(
            stock.prices = map(ticker.symbol, 
                       function(.x) get_stock_prices(.x, 
                                                     return_format = "tibble",
                                                     from = from,
                                                     to = to)
                     ),
               log.returns  = map(stock.prices, 
                       function(.x) get_log_returns(.x, return_format = "tibble")),
            mean.log.returns = map_dbl(log.returns, ~ mean(.$Log.Returns)),
            sd.log.returns   = map_dbl(log.returns, ~ sd(.$Log.Returns)),
            n.trade.days = map_dbl(stock.prices, nrow)
          ) 
}

The purpose of this code is to list the extracted symbols, the stock prices, log return, mean.log.return. sd.log.returns and n.trade.days and this doesnt work. The map() function, mutate() and getsymbols() keeps throwing up an error message that I cant figure what the solutions is. PlEASE HELP! I keep getting this error message below
Error in mutate():
ℹ In argument: stock.prices = map(...).
Caused by error in map():
ℹ In index: 24.
Caused by error in getSymbols.yahoo():
! Unable to import “AMCR”.
Timeout was reached: [query2.finance.yahoo.com] Failed to connect to query2.finance.yahoo.com port 443 after 10001 ms: Timeout was reached`

Please add all library calls. [MRE]

AMCR is 24th symbol, so there are a couple of possibilities.  There may be a problem with the "AMCR" symbol for some reason.  Maybe you are calling the  get_stock_prices() function too quickly and exceeding the allowable limit, try adding a delay. Maybe the price history doesn't go back to 2007 with that symbol.

library(quantmod), library(xts), library(rvest), library(tidyverse), library(stringr), library(forcats), library(lubridate)
